# SSIS Package - From One Table to Infinite Tables Depending on Data

Tags: ssis

I have a simple requirement. I have a table with Product Names and their Count. I want to create a SSIS package to extract data from one table to infinite tables based on Product Name. 
In table if i have 10 products then SSIS package should create 10 tables dynamically with one product in each table.

**Table Name : Products**

```
ProductName  , QuantitySold
   ABC              10
   xyz              15
   Testing          25
```

**Table Name : ABC**

```
ProductName  , QuantitySold
   ABC              10
```

**Table Name : XYZ**

```
ProductName  , QuantitySold
   xyz              15
```

**Table Name : Testing**

```
ProductName  , QuantitySold
   ABC              10
```

Comment: Really? One table and based on the values in that table, you're going to create a 2 column table with 1 row in it?

Comment: yes based on the requirement

Comment: What part of it do you not know how to do?   In fact, why do you even need to use SSIS?

Comment: @Ally that's a really odd requirement.  I mean you could just train the users on how to use a WHERE clause.  Does it have to be this exact solution?

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, you're looking at something like

[image]

The concept is that you will identify all the product names in the table and perform 2 tasks on each row: Create the target table, if needed. Run a query against your source for that one row and load it into the table.

### Variables

I have 6 variables declared

[image]

Query_TableCreateBase is a big string that formatted looks like

```
IF  NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        sys.tables AS T
    WHERE
        T.name = '<Table/>'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.<Table/>
    (
        ProductName varchar(30) NOT NULL
    ,   QuantitySold int NOT NULL
    );
END
```

I have expressions on Query_Source, Query_TableCreate and TargetTable

Query_Source expression

```
"SELECT ProductName, QuantitySold FROM (
    VALUES
        ('ABC', 10)
    ,   ('xyz', 15)
    ,   ('Testing', 25)
) Products(ProductName, QuantitySold) WHERE ProductName = '" + @[User::ProductName] + "'"
```

Query_TableCreate expression

```
replace(@[User::Query_TableCreateBase], "<Table/>", @[User::ProductName])
```

TargetTable expression

```
"[dbo].[" +@[User::ProductName] + "]"
```

### SQL Get Rows

I simulate your Products table with a query. I load those results into a variable named RS_Product.

```
SELECT 
ProductName
FROM
(
    VALUES
        ('ABC', 10)
    ,   ('xyz', 15)
    ,   ('Testing', 25)
) Products(ProductName, QuantitySold);
```

### FELC Shred Results

I use a Foreach Loop Container, set to process an ADO Result set and parse out the 0th column into our ProductName variable

### SQL Create Table if needed

This is a query that gets evaluated out to something like

```
IF  NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        sys.tables AS T
    WHERE
        T.name = 'Foo'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Foo
    (
        ProductName varchar(30) NOT NULL
    ,   QuantitySold int NOT NULL
    );
END
```

### DFT Load Table

I have this set as DelayValidation = true as the table may not exist right up until it gets the signal to start.

Again, simulating your Products table, my query looks like

```
SELECT ProductName, QuantitySold FROM (
    VALUES
        ('ABC', 10)
    ,   ('xyz', 15)
    ,   ('Testing', 25)
) Products(ProductName, QuantitySold) WHERE ProductName = 'Foo'
```

### Wrapup

Strictly speaking, the data flow is not required. It could all be done through your Execute SQL Task if we pulled back all the columns in our source query.

### Biml implemenation

Biml, the Business Intelligence Markup Language, describes the platform for business intelligence. Here, we're going to use it to describe the ETL. [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com), is a free add on for Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT that addresses a host of shortcomings with it. Specifically, we're going to use the ability to transform a Biml file describing ETL into an SSIS package. This has the added benefit of providing you a mechanism for being able to generate exactly the solution I'm describing versus clicking through many tedious dialogue boxes.

The following code assumes you have a default instance on your local machine and that within tempdb, you have a table called Foo.

```
    use tempdb;
    GO
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Foo
    (
        ProductName varchar(30) NOT NULL
    ,   QuantitySold int NOT NULL
    );
```

Save the following script into a .biml file which when you add to your SSIS project will show up under the Miscellaneous virtual folder. Right click, choose Generate SSIS Package and it should create a package called `so_27320726`

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="tempdb" ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_27320726" ConstraintMode="Parallel" >
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="ProductName" DataType="String">Foo</Variable>
                <Variable Name="Query_Source" DataType="String" EvaluateAsExpression="true">"SELECT ProductName, QuantitySold FROM (
    VALUES
        ('ABC', 10)
    ,   ('xyz', 15)
    ,   ('Testing', 25)
) Products(ProductName, QuantitySold) WHERE ProductName = '" + @[User::ProductName] + "'"</Variable>
                <Variable Name="Query_TableCreate" DataType="String" EvaluateAsExpression="true"><![CDATA[replace(@[User::Query_TableCreateBase], "<Table/>", @[User::ProductName])]]></Variable>
                <Variable Name="Query_TableCreateBase" DataType="String" ><![CDATA[IF  NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        sys.tables AS T
    WHERE
        T.name = '<Table/>'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.<Table/>
    (
        ProductName varchar(30) NOT NULL
    ,   QuantitySold int NOT NULL
    );
END]]></Variable>
                <Variable Name="RS_Product" DataType="Object" />
                <Variable Name="TargetTable" DataType="String" EvaluateAsExpression="true">"[dbo].[" +@[User::ProductName] + "]"</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <ExecuteSQL Name="SQL Get Rows" ConnectionName="tempdb" ResultSet="Full">
                    <Variables>
                        <Variable Name="Variable" DataType="Int32" IncludeInDebugDump="Include">0</Variable>
                    </Variables>
                    <Results>
                        <Result Name="0" VariableName="User.RS_Product" />
                    </Results>
                    <DirectInput>SELECT
*
FROM
(
    VALUES
        ('ABC', 10)
    ,   ('xyz', 15)
    ,   ('Testing', 25)
) Products(ProductName, QuantitySold);</DirectInput>
                </ExecuteSQL>
                <ForEachAdoLoop Name="FELC Shred Results" ConstraintMode="Linear" SourceVariableName="User.RS_Product">
                    <PrecedenceConstraints>
                        <Inputs>
                            <Input OutputPathName="SQL Get Rows.Output" SsisName="Constraint" />
                        </Inputs>
                    </PrecedenceConstraints>
                    <Tasks>
                        <ExecuteSQL Name="SQL Create Table if needed" ConnectionName="tempdb">
                            <VariableInput VariableName="User.Query_TableCreate" />
                        </ExecuteSQL>
                        <Dataflow Name="DFT Load Table" DelayValidation="true">
                            <Transformations>
                                <OleDbSource Name="OLE_SRC Get Data" DefaultCodePage="1252" ConnectionName="tempdb">
                                    <VariableInput VariableName="User.Query_Source" />
                                </OleDbSource>
                                <OleDbDestination Name="OLE_DST Save data" ConnectionName="tempdb" >
                                    <TableFromVariableOutput VariableName="User.TargetTable" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <Column SourceColumn="ProductName" TargetColumn="ProductName" />
                                        <Column SourceColumn="QuantitySold" TargetColumn="QuantitySold" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </OleDbDestination>
                            </Transformations>
                        </Dataflow>
                    </Tasks>
                    <VariableMappings>
                        <VariableMapping Name="0" VariableName="User.ProductName" />
                    </VariableMappings>
                </ForEachAdoLoop>
            </Tasks>
            <Connections>
                <Connection ConnectionName="tempdb" />
            </Connections>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```